# how to get array from unrealized data

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

my code-

```
$order[$j][1]=$q16;
<input type="hidden" name="hdnOrder" value="<?php echo htmlentities(serialize($order)); ?>">
```

on my next page-

```
$order =  array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', unserialize($_REQUEST['hdnOrder']));
```

it gives me the following error-
`Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array`

I want order value in array form because of-

```
foreach($order as $row)
```

Comment: What does `$_REQUEST['hdnOrder']` look like?

Comment: Perhaps not exactly your question, but why not store that hdnOrder in a session or database and then fetch it after the form? The way you have it the user can tamper with it and then submit an erroneous hdnOrder

Comment: You put "unrealized" in your title.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `htmlentities()` you are doing on the data.

Use `htmlspecialchars(serialize($order), ENT_QUOTES)` instead and do a `htmlspecialchars_decode()` afterwards.

```
$order =  array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', 
 unserialize(htmlspecialchars_decode($_REQUEST['hdnOrder'], ENT_QUOTES)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use urldecode/urlencode instead of htmlentities.